# MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe" after upgrading to VS 2017

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, npm-install

I installed VS 2017 recently, now when i do an npm install i get this error. This project is compiling well in my other machine running VS 2015.

why does that keep asking for VCBuild.exe shouldn't it be looking for MSBuild.exe.

This is a Single page application that used to compile without any issues in vs 2015

Comment: what .Net you've installed ?

Comment: i have 4.7.02046 installed